# Arduino Leonardo Upload issue with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: arduino-ide, bare-conductive

I got a bare conductive board ( which is based on arduino leonardo ) . I was trying to upload a blink sketch using arduion 1.5.7. But its always failing and here is the log. I never work a leonardo before. Any ideas what is happing with this ?

```
Build options changed, rebuilding all

/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Blink.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Blink.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/wiring_analog.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/wiring_digital.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_shift.c -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/wiring_shift.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.c -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/WInterrupts.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/hooks.c -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/hooks.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.c -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/wiring_pulse.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/wiring.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial3.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Tone.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial1.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial2.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Print.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Print.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HID.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HID.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/USBCore.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HardwareSerial.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/IPAddress.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/IPAddress.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/WMath.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/WString.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/main.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/main.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial0.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/new.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/new.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Stream.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Stream.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=157 -DARDUINO_AVR_BARETOUCH -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2A6E -DUSB_PID=0x8003 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Bare Conductive" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Touch Board" -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/CDC.cpp -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/CDC.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/wiring_analog.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/wiring_digital.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/wiring_shift.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/WInterrupts.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/hooks.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/wiring_pulse.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/wiring.c.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Tone.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Print.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HID.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/USBCore.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HardwareSerial.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/IPAddress.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/WMath.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/WString.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/main.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/new.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Stream.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/CDC.cpp.o 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -w -Os -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega32u4 -o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Blink.cpp.elf /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Blink.cpp.o /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/core.a -L/tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp -lm 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Blink.cpp.elf /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Blink.cpp.eep 
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Blink.cpp.elf /tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Blink.cpp.hex 

Sketch uses 4,798 bytes (16%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28,672 bytes.
Global variables use 157 bytes (6%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,403 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,560 bytes.
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port /dev/ttyACM0
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM0, } / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {} => {}
PORTS {} / {/dev/ttyACM0, } => {/dev/ttyACM0, }
Found upload port: /dev/ttyACM0
/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/build5447563659949358969.tmp/Blink.cpp.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr  3 2014 at 21:52:43
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/achayan/Downloads/arduino-1.5.7/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/root/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: Send: . [1b] 
avrdude: Send: S [53] 
avrdude: Recv: C [43] 

avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

And My dmesg output is

```
[ 3616.984079] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using uhci_hcd
[ 3617.155216] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2a6e, idProduct=8003
[ 3617.155224] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3617.155229] usb 4-2: Product: Touch Board
[ 3617.155234] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Bare Conductive
[ 3617.158323] cdc_acm 4-2:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[ 3617.158359] cdc_acm 4-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 3617.166427] input: Bare Conductive Touch Board as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.2/input/input22
[ 3617.166675] hid-generic 0003:2A6E:8003.0007: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [Bare Conductive Touch Board] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-2/input2
```

And My lsusb output

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b179 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 18d1:4ee2 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (debug)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Bluetooth 2.0 Interface [Broadcom BCM2045]
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 011: ID 2a6e:8003  
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1d57:0008 Xenta 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the arduino.cc forums. Post your logs, and you MIGHT get an answer that'll work. The guys who developed the Leonardo got it to work with Ubuntu 10.04 without a special device driver. I use Ubuntu like you but not the magic 10.04 version and was forced to give up on the Leonardo despite heroic effort.

The problem is that 32u4 chip the Leonardo (and Micro) use. Instead of having a separate FTDI chip like a good ol' UNO, it handles USB on its own. With a bootloader on a Leonardo that enables only USB to be used (besides ICSP) Windows needs a funny .inf file to make it work. But Linux? In this case, Windows of a given version is Windows is Windows. Linux boxes are more like people in that each has its own personality, given the zillion distributions and versions thereof.

I'm convinced that the Leonardo developers merely got lucky with Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: This is not an answer.